# How do I transfer values of a CSV files between certain dates to another CSV file based on the dates in the rows in that file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Long question: I have two CSV files, one called SF1 which has quarterly data (only 4 times a year) with a datekey column, and one called DAILY which gives data every day. This is financial data so there are ticker columns.

I need to grab the quarterly data for SF1 and write it to the DAILY csv file for all the days that are in between when we get the next quarterly data.

For example, `AAPL` has quarterly data released in SF1 on 2010-01-01 and its next earnings report is going to be on 2010-03-04. I then need every row in the DAILY file with ticker `AAPL` between the dates 2010-01-01 until 2010-03-04 to have the same information as that one row on that date in the SF1 file.

So far, I have made a python dictionary that goes through the SF1 file and adds the dates to a list which is the value of the ticker keys in the dictionary. I thought about potentially getting rid of the previous string and just referencing the string that is in the dictionary to go and search for the data to write to the DAILY file.

Some of the columns needed to transfer from the SF1 file to the DAILY file are:

`['accoci', 'assets', 'assetsavg', 'assetsc', 'assetsnc', 'assetturnover', 'bvps', 'capex', 'cashneq', 'cashnequsd', 'cor', 'consolinc', 'currentratio', 'de', 'debt', 'debtc', 'debtnc', 'debtusd', 'deferredrev', 'depamor', 'deposits', 'divyield', 'dps', 'ebit']`

Code so far:

```
for ind, row in sf1.iterrows():
    sf1_date = row['datekey']
    sf1_ticker = row['ticker']
    company_date.setdefault(sf1_ticker, []).append(sf1_date)
```

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

SF1 csv:

```
ticker,dimension,calendardate,datekey,reportperiod,lastupdated,accoci,assets,assetsavg,assetsc,assetsnc,assetturnover,bvps,capex,cashneq,cashnequsd,cor,consolinc,currentratio,de,debt,debtc,debtnc,debtusd,deferredrev,depamor,deposits,divyield,dps,ebit,ebitda,ebitdamargin,ebitdausd,ebitusd,ebt,eps,epsdil,epsusd,equity,equityavg,equityusd,ev,evebit,evebitda,fcf,fcfps,fxusd,gp,grossmargin,intangibles,intexp,invcap,invcapavg,inventory,investments,investmentsc,investmentsnc,liabilities,liabilitiesc,liabilitiesnc,marketcap,ncf,ncfbus,ncfcommon,ncfdebt,ncfdiv,ncff,ncfi,ncfinv,ncfo,ncfx,netinc,netinccmn,netinccmnusd,netincdis,netincnci,netmargin,opex,opinc,payables,payoutratio,pb,pe,pe1,ppnenet,prefdivis,price,ps,ps1,receivables,retearn,revenue,revenueusd,rnd,roa,roe,roic,ros,sbcomp,sgna,sharefactor,sharesbas,shareswa,shareswadil,sps,tangibles,taxassets,taxexp,taxliabilities,tbvps,workingcapital
A,ARQ,2020-09-14,2020-09-14,2020-09-14,2020-09-14,53000000,7107000000,,4982000000,2125000000,,10.219,-30000000,1368000000,1368000000,1160000000,131000000,2.41,0.584,665000000,111000000,554000000,665000000,281000000,96000000,0,0.0,0.0,202000000,298000000,0.133,298000000,202000000,202000000,0.3,0.3,0.3,4486000000,,4486000000,50960600000,,,354000000,0.806,1.0,1086000000,0.484,0,0,4337000000,,1567000000,42000000,42000000,0,2621000000,2067000000,554000000,51663600000,1368000000,-160000000,2068000000,111000000,0,1192000000,-208000000,-42000000,384000000,0,131000000,131000000,131000000,0,0,0.058,915000000,171000000,635000000,0.0,11.517,,,1408000000,0,114.3,,,1445000000,131000000,2246000000,2246000000,290000000,,,,,0,625000000,1.0,452000000,439000000,440000000,5.116,7107000000,0,71000000,113000000,16.189,2915000000
```

Daily csv:

```
ticker,date,lastupdated,ev,evebit,evebitda,marketcap,pb,pe,ps
A,2020-09-14,2020-09-14,31617.1,36.3,26.8,30652.1,6.2,44.4,5.9
```

Ideal csv after code run (with all the numbers for the assets under them):

```
ticker,date,lastupdated,ev,evebit,evebitda,marketcap,pb,pe,ps,accoci,assets,assetsavg,assetsc,assetsnc,assetturnover,bvps,capex,cashneq,cashnequsd,cor,consolinc,currentratio,de,debt,debtc,debtnc,debtusd,deferredrev,depamor,deposits,divyield,dps,ebit,ebitda,ebitdamargin,ebitdausd,ebitusd,ebt,eps,epsdil,epsusd,equity,equityavg,equityusd,ev,evebit,evebitda,fcf,fcfps,fxusd,gp,grossmargin,intangibles,intexp,invcap,invcapavg,inventory,investments,investmentsc,investmentsnc,liabilities,liabilitiesc,liabilitiesnc,marketcap,ncf,ncfbus,ncfcommon,ncfdebt,ncfdiv,ncff,ncfi,ncfinv,ncfo,ncfx,netinc,netinccmn,netinccmnusd,netincdis,netincnci,netmargin,opex,opinc,payables,payoutratio,pb,pe,pe1,ppnenet,prefdivis,price,ps,ps1,receivables,retearn,revenue,revenueusd,rnd,roa,roe,roic,ros,sbcomp,sgna,sharefactor,sharesbas,shareswa,shareswadil,sps,tangibles,taxassets,taxexp,taxliabilities,tbvps,workingcapital
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a cut down example showing a few CSV lines with a desired output?

Comment: @MartinEvans just did that, hopefully, it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is `merge_asof` it allows to merge date columns to the closer immediately after or before in the second dataframe.

As is it not explicit, I will assume here that `daily.date` and `sf1.datekey` are both true date columns, meaning that their dtype is `datetime64[ns]`. `merge_asof` cannot use string columns with an `object` dtype.

I will also assume that you do not want the ev  evebit  evebitda  marketcap   pb    pe   and ps columns from the `sf1` dataframes because their names conflict with columns from `daily` (more on that later):

Code could be:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(daily, sf1.drop(columns=['dimension', 'calendardate',
                                            'reportperiod','lastupdated',
                                            'ev', 'evebit', 'evebitda',
                                            'marketcap', 'pb', 'pe', 'ps']),
                                   by = 'ticker', left_on='date',
                                   right_on='datekey')
```

You get the following list of columns: ticker, date, lastupdated, ev, evebit, evebitda, marketcap, pb, pe, ps, datekey, accoci, assets, assetsavg, assetsc, assetsnc, assetturnover, bvps, capex, cashneq, cashnequsd, cor, consolinc, currentratio, de, debt, debtc, debtnc, debtusd, deferredrev, depamor, deposits, divyield, dps, ebit, ebitda, ebitdamargin, ebitdausd, ebitusd, ebt, eps, epsdil, epsusd, equity, equityavg, equityusd, fcf, fcfps, fxusd, gp, grossmargin, intangibles, intexp, invcap, invcapavg, inventory, investments, investmentsc, investmentsnc, liabilities, liabilitiesc, liabilitiesnc, ncf, ncfbus, ncfcommon, ncfdebt, ncfdiv, ncff, ncfi, ncfinv, ncfo, ncfx, netinc, netinccmn, netinccmnusd, netincdis, netincnci, netmargin, opex, opinc, payables, payoutratio, pe1, ppnenet, prefdivis, price, ps1, receivables, retearn, revenue, revenueusd, rnd, roa, roe, roic, ros, sbcomp, sgna, sharefactor, sharesbas, shareswa, shareswadil, sps, tangibles, taxassets, taxexp, taxliabilities, tbvps, workingcapital with their relevant values

---

If you want to keep the columns existing in both dataframe, you will have to rename them. Here is a possible code adding `_d` to the names of column from daily:

```
df2 = pd.merge_asof(daily, sf1.drop(columns=['dimension', 'calendardate',
                                            'reportperiod','lastupdated']),
                                   by = 'ticker', left_on='date',
                                   right_on='datekey', suffixes=('_d', ''))
```

The list of columns is now: ticker, date, lastupdated, ev_d, evebit_d, evebitda_d, marketcap_d, pb_d, pe_d, ps_d, datekey, accoci, ...

Comment: Great answer! I changed a few small things now and I'm getting an error. For the SF1 file, I'm now using ```calendardate``` instead of datekey. I've also sorted both dataframes by ticker and by date/calendardate values. Code: ```df = pd.merge_asof(daily, sf1, by = 'ticker', left_on='date', right_on='calendardate', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(value=100, unit='D'), direction='backward')
``` I now get this error:  ```pandas.errors.MergeError: key must be integer or timestamp
```

Comment: @george.adams1: have you controlled the dtype of date and calendardate? This must both be `datetime64[ns]`...

Comment: I just fixed that now. I'm having another issue: ```ValueError: left keys must be sorted
``` I thought I had solved this before but I guess I hadn't. I added these lines of code before to try and sort the dataframes: ```daily = daily.sort_values('date', ascending=True)
sf1 = sf1.sort_values('calendardate', ascending=True)
daily = daily.sort_values('ticker')
sf1 = sf1.sort_values('ticker')```

Comment: You can (and should...) sort on one single pass even for multiple columns: `daily = daily.sort_value(['ticker', 'date'])`.

Comment: I changed the code to: ```daily = daily.sort_values(['ticker', 'date'])
sf1 = sf1.sort_values(['ticker', 'calendardate'])``` I still get this error: ```ValueError: left keys must be sorted``` In what order do the keys need to be for ```merge_asof``` to work?